# Objective-C AVAssetExportSession only audio

Tags: objective-c, audio, file-type, avassetexportsession

How can I use AVAssetExportSession to only export audio to, let's say, an *.aif or an *.mp3 file? Whenever I try providing anything other than `@"com.apple.quicktime-movie"` for the `outputFileType`-property, it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because .mp3 is not a supported export file type